Hide and display Text based on actionButton and selected choices of shiny widget
In the shiny app below I have 2 shiny widgets related to each other and then a Preview button which is activated when we have values in shools widgets. When I click Preview also a text is displayed. The issue is that I want this text to be hidden when I have no values in my school widgets. And then displayed again when I have at least one school selected and click Preview.
library(renv)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)
early<-structure(list(temp_record_id = c("3_8", "3_14", "3_20", "3_35", 
                                         "3_45", "3_49", "3_59", "3_67", "3_72", "3_79"), district_number = c("0001", 
                                                                                                              "0001", "0001", "0014", "0038", "0110", "0113", "0196", "0200", 
                                                                                                              "0273"), district_type = c("33", "33", "33", "31", "31", "31", 
                                                                                                                                         "31", "31", "31", "31"), school_number = c("012", "015", "036", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    "006", "001", "001", "100", "007", "002", "007"), grade = c("03", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03"), subject = c("Reading", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Reading", "Reading", "Reading"), group_category = c("All Categories", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "All Categories", "All Categories", "All Categories", "All Categories", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "All Categories", "All Categories", "All Categories", "All Categories", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "All Categories"), student_group = c("All Students", "All Students", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "All Students", "All Students", "All Students", "All Students", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "All Students", "All Students", "All Students", "All Students"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ), school_year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           2015, 2015, 2015), denominator = c(40, 31, 21, 21, 12, 18, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              22, 14, 80), numerator = c(17, 12, 9, 10, 4, 13, NA, 19, 11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         68), school_name = c("Ascension Catholic School", "Risen Christ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "St. Helena Catholic School", "Al-Amal School", "St. Mary's Mission", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "St. Joseph", "Immanuel Lutheran School", "St. Joseph's Catholic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "St. John The Baptist", "Our Lady Of Grace"), district_name = c("Nonpublic School", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", "Nonpublic School", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Nonpublic School"), county_name = c("Hennepin", "Hennepin", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Hennepin", "Anoka", "Beltrami", "Carver", "Cass", "Dakota", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Dakota", "Hennepin"), school_classification = c("00", "00", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "00", "40", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"), school_name_unique = c("Ascension Catholic School 0001-33-012", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Risen Christ 0001-33-015", "St. Helena Catholic School 0001-33-036", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Al-Amal School 0014-31-006", "St. Mary's Mission 0038-31-001", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "St. Joseph 0110-31-001", "Immanuel Lutheran School 0113-31-100", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "St. Joseph's Catholic 0196-31-007", "St. John The Baptist 0200-31-002", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Our Lady Of Grace 0273-31-007"), id = c("0001-33-012", "0001-33-015", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "0001-33-036", "0014-31-006", "0038-31-001", "0110-31-001", "0113-31-100", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "0196-31-007", "0200-31-002", "0273-31-007")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

all_districts <- unique(sort(early$district_name))
all_schools <- unique(sort(early$school_name_unique))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("CIA Data Prep"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Select Schools to Include"),
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(inputId = "districts",
                                label = "Districts:",
                                choices = all_districts,
                                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                                multiple = TRUE),
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(inputId = "schools",
                                label = "Schools:",
                                choices = "",
                                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                                selected = "",
                                multiple = TRUE),
      shiny::actionButton(inputId = "runButton", label = "Preview", disabled = TRUE),
      shiny::actionButton(inputId = "downButton", label = "Download", disabled = TRUE)),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6,uiOutput("ear"))
      )
      
      )
      
    )
  )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$districts, {
    if (!is.null(input$districts) && length(input$districts) > 0) {
      shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "schools",
        choices = early %>% dplyr::arrange(district_name, school_name_unique) %>% dplyr::filter(district_name %in% input$districts) %>% dplyr::select(school_name_unique) %>% unique() %>% pull()
      )
    } else {
      shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "schools",
        choices = "",
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        selected = ""
      )
      updateActionButton(session, "runButton", disabled = TRUE)
      updateActionButton(session, "downButton", disabled = TRUE)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$schools, {
    if (!is.null(input$schools) &&
        length(input$schools) > 0 && any(input$schools != "")) {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "runButton",
                         disabled = FALSE)
    } else {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "runButton",
                         disabled = TRUE)
      updateActionButton(inputId = "downButton",
                         disabled = TRUE)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    if (input$runButton > 0) {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "downButton",
                         disabled = FALSE)
    }
  })
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    if (is.null(input$schools) ||
        any(input$schools == "") || input$runButton == 0) {
      output$ear <- renderUI({HTML("")})
    }
    
    else{
      output$ear <- renderUI({
        HTML("Early Reading Grades")
        
      })
      
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


I split the observeEvent content on input$runButton into two observeEvent, one for rendering the empty text and one for rendering the non-empty text. It should fulfill all requirements now.
library(renv)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)

early <-
  structure(
    list(
      temp_record_id = c(
        "3_8",
        "3_14",
        "3_20",
        "3_35",
        "3_45",
        "3_49",
        "3_59",
        "3_67",
        "3_72",
        "3_79"
      ),
      district_number = c(
        "0001",
        "0001",
        "0001",
        "0014",
        "0038",
        "0110",
        "0113",
        "0196",
        "0200",
        "0273"
      ),
      district_type = c("33", "33", "33", "31", "31", "31",
                        "31", "31", "31", "31"),
      school_number = c(
        "012",
        "015",
        "036",
        "006",
        "001",
        "001",
        "100",
        "007",
        "002",
        "007"
      ),
      grade = c("03",
                "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03"),
      subject = c(
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading",
        "Reading"
      ),
      group_category = c(
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories",
        "All Categories"
      ),
      student_group = c(
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students",
        "All Students"
      ),
      school_year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015,
                      2015, 2015, 2015),
      denominator = c(40, 31, 21, 21, 12, 18, NA,
                      22, 14, 80),
      numerator = c(17, 12, 9, 10, 4, 13, NA, 19, 11,
                    68),
      school_name = c(
        "Ascension Catholic School",
        "Risen Christ",
        "St. Helena Catholic School",
        "Al-Amal School",
        "St. Mary's Mission",
        "St. Joseph",
        "Immanuel Lutheran School",
        "St. Joseph's Catholic",
        "St. John The Baptist",
        "Our Lady Of Grace"
      ),
      district_name = c(
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School",
        "Nonpublic School"
      ),
      county_name = c(
        "Hennepin",
        "Hennepin",
        "Hennepin",
        "Anoka",
        "Beltrami",
        "Carver",
        "Cass",
        "Dakota",
        "Dakota",
        "Hennepin"
      ),
      school_classification = c("00", "00",
                                "00", "40", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"),
      school_name_unique = c(
        "Ascension Catholic School 0001-33-012",
        "Risen Christ 0001-33-015",
        "St. Helena Catholic School 0001-33-036",
        "Al-Amal School 0014-31-006",
        "St. Mary's Mission 0038-31-001",
        "St. Joseph 0110-31-001",
        "Immanuel Lutheran School 0113-31-100",
        "St. Joseph's Catholic 0196-31-007",
        "St. John The Baptist 0200-31-002",
        "Our Lady Of Grace 0273-31-007"
      ),
      id = c(
        "0001-33-012",
        "0001-33-015",
        "0001-33-036",
        "0014-31-006",
        "0038-31-001",
        "0110-31-001",
        "0113-31-100",
        "0196-31-007",
        "0200-31-002",
        "0273-31-007"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  -10L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

all_districts <- unique(sort(early$district_name))
all_schools <- unique(sort(early$school_name_unique))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("CIA Data Prep"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Select Schools to Include"),
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "districts",
        label = "Districts:",
        choices = all_districts,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE
      ),
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = "schools",
        label = "Schools:",
        choices = "",
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        selected = "",
        multiple = TRUE
      ),
      shiny::actionButton(
        inputId = "runButton",
        label = "Preview",
        disabled = TRUE
      ),
      shiny::actionButton(
        inputId = "downButton",
        label = "Download",
        disabled = TRUE
      )
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput(
      "ear"
    ))))
    
  ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$districts, {
    if (!is.null(input$districts) && length(input$districts) > 0) {
      shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "schools",
        choices = early %>% dplyr::arrange(district_name, school_name_unique) %>% dplyr::filter(district_name %in% input$districts) %>% dplyr::select(school_name_unique) %>% unique() %>% pull()
      )
    } else {
      shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "schools",
        choices = "",
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        selected = ""
      )
      updateActionButton(session, "runButton", disabled = TRUE)
      updateActionButton(session, "downButton", disabled = TRUE)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$schools, {
    if (!is.null(input$schools) &&
        length(input$schools) > 0 && any(input$schools != "")) {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "runButton",
                         disabled = FALSE)
    } else {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "runButton",
                         disabled = TRUE)
      updateActionButton(inputId = "downButton",
                         disabled = TRUE)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    if (input$runButton > 0) {
      updateActionButton(inputId = "downButton",
                         disabled = FALSE)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$schools, {
    if (is.null(input$schools) || any(input$schools == "")) {
      output$ear <- renderUI({
        HTML("")
      })
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    output$ear <- renderUI({
      HTML("Early Reading Grades")
    })
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

